# Program unresponsive on clicking a button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create a simple calculator using Tkinter, but I'm facing a problem. First see the relevant code:

```
entry_text = StringVar()
inout = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)
inout.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="nsew")

def equals():
    print("Equal button is clicked")
    get_answer = True

def divide():
    tempvar = entry_text.get()
    num1 = int(tempvar)
    entry_text.set("")
    while get_answer == False:
        tempvar2 = entry_text.get()
        try:
            num2 = int(tempvar2)
        except ValueError:
            num2 = 0
    print("I'm out of the loop.")
    answer = num1 / num2
    entry_text.set(answer)
```

Here I'm creating a function for the `divide` button. The functionality of the button is whenever you click on the button, it takes the instantaneous value of the `entry_text` variable, stores it in a temporary variable and resets the value of `entry_text` variable. Then it runs a loop for collecting the next value of `entry_text` until the equal button is clicked. But the problem lies just here. Whenever I click on `divide` button, the GUI becomes unresponsive, and I don't get to enter the next value for the divide operation and get out of the loop.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `while get_answer == False:` interrupts the `mainloop`. As long as the while loop runs there can no events proceed.

Comment: First avoid using while loop in a tkinter application as it will blocks tkinter from handling pending events.  Second you create local variable `get_answer` inside `equals()`, not updating the global one (assume there is one).

Comment: @acw1668 Your assumption is correct, but can you tell what should I do exactly in the form of a detailed answer, as your second line of the answer is a bit confusing?

Comment: @acw1668 And also what kind of method should I use to update the temporary variable in real time, is there a method in Entry object like ontextchanged or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using while loop in a tkinter application because it will block tkinter `mainloop` from handling pending events.

Also, `get_answer` inside `equals()` is a local variable because you haven't declare it as a global using `global get_answer`.

Actually you should perform the required operation inside `equals()`, but you need to store the first number and selected operation as global variables:

```py
num1 = 0
operator = None

def equals():
    global num1, operator
    print("Equal button is clicked")
    try:
        tempvar = entry_text.get()
        num2 = float(tempvar)  # used float() instead of int()
        if operator == '/' and num2 != 0:
            answer = num1 / num2
            entry_text.set(answer)
            operator = None # reset operator
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid value', tempvar)

def divide():
    global num1, operator
    try:
        tempvar = entry_text.get()
        num1 = float(tempvar)  # used float() instead of int()
        entry_text.set("")
        operator = '/'   # save the operator
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid value', tempvar)
```

Comment: A lot of thanks to you! You solved all of my problems, I included this in my code with slight modifications. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The program becomes unresponsive as the `while` loop continues forever and never breaks, as the variable `get_answer` is never changed to `True`.

> You can’t click on any button, because the `while` loop keeps running and can’t break without the condition given to it turns `false` or it is manually told to `break` after some number of loops.